# ChartJS Tooltip - Change Data Format Displayed

Tags: chart.js, date-fns

I've created a horizontal floating bar chart using ChartJS. The data I am passing in is formatted as:

```
[
   {
     rowName: 'Project 1',
     startDate: '2021-03-15',
     endDate: '2021-04-20',
   }
]
```

Where my x axis shows a month/year and my y axis shows the rowName. I've added chartjs-adapater-date-fns but in order to get the floating bars to work, I've had to convert the startDate and endDate into new dates and then use the .getTime() function to retrieve a number for the data the chart expects. E.g. [new Date(startDate).getTime(), new Date(endDate).getTime()].

On my tooltip, it shows the label as rowName which is what I'm wanting, however the data value shows as the two number values being passed in.

I'm  wanting to show the tooltip in the following format:

- Project 1
- Start Date: 05/03/2021
- End Date: 20/04/2021

What is the best way of doing this?

Note: I have consoled the context and found that data.raw provides me with 2021-05-03,2021-04-20 if that is of any use?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Instead of new date pass your input date , Tooltip will show with formatted date value.

var barOption = {
                    tooltips: {
                      callbacks: {
                          label: function(t, d) {
                          this.date=new Date();
                       let formated_date = this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'dd/MM/yyy');
    return formated_date;
                         },
                      },
                    },
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).